# Do Count In Logstash and Plot It

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have built a platform as logstash+elasticsearch+kibana and forwarded RabbitMQ logs to it. I have organized the charts related to indeces (connection status, type, timestamps etc.) on Kibana. It is quite well so far. But I want to plot number of currently active connections in RabbitMQ. The idea I have found is to increment counter for each connection with status `ACCEPTED` and decrement it for each with status `CLOSING`. This will be done accumulatively and the value is plotted. 
It seems to me that I should do the operation on logstash side when a RabbitMQ log is recieved. How can I achieve this goal? Any other idea is welcomed, any help is appreciated.